# Men going shirtless

Tags: tznius-modesty, men-male

I know the question has been asked before, but Im still looking for more info. Other questions and answers focus on the permisability of it. Im pretty sure its mutar, but wondering if its advisable.

In the comfort of your own home, <strike>can</strike> Should you go topless during exercise or just in general? Meaning is it appropriate for a home where the children are in yeshiva ?

What about running in the park? Is a t-shirt and shorts outfit fine?

What about boys/men walking around in boxers ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mi Yodeya. Great to have you here. I hope your question gets opened again so we can answer it now that you've edited it.

Comment: I wish it would get reopened. I dont understand why it was closed.

Comment: in case it is not reopened, is there any other way for me to get answers to these questions ?

Comment: Perhaps delete it and ask it again. Now that the wording is updated, it should be ok. I'm new here so double check that's not against the rules